# Как указать yii2 что запрос отправлен при помощи ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

сами запросы приходят, ведется работа с ними, но `$request->isAjax` возвращает `false`.
почему так и как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно было указать в хедере, что это `ajax`

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
```